# Best way to refresh a Web.UI.Page in response to a callback from another thread

Tags: c#-4.0

What is the best way to accomplish the following in a web page lifecycle?

```
    protected void btnTestAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MainThreadID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        TestBLL bl = new TestBLL();
        bl.OnBeginWork += OnBeginWork;
        bl.OnEndWork += OnEndWork;
        bl.OnProgressUpdate += OnWork;
        ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(bl.PerformBeginWork);
        Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        newThread.Start();
     }
```

Then on the OnWorkEvent I enter:

```
 private  void OnWork(AsyncProgress workProgress, ref bool abortProcess)
    {
        string s = String.Format("MAIN TREAD: {0} WORKER THREAD: {1} COUNT :{2} COMPLETE: {3} REMAINING: {4}", 
                                this.MainThreadID, 
                                workProgress.ThreadID, 
                                workProgress.NumberOfOperationsTotal, 
                                workProgress.NumberOfOperationsCompleted, 
                                workProgress.NumberOfOperationsRemaining);
        lbl.Text = s;
        lb.Items.Add(s);
        //.ProcessMessages(); Response.Redirect???<-- Here I want to rfresh the page. During debug the test variables are proper
    }
```

Please excuse my ignorance; I have never done this with a Web.UI.Page. What is the best way to update the UI from a delegate callback in another thread?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest ajax.

Your button click will cause a browser postback.  From that point there is nothing really to "force" the browser (client side) to do another postback unless the user "does something"

Using ajax you can do an async call that will respond when the call is complete.

There are multiple ways to do this, but i personally use jquery.

here is an example of a possible ajax call using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../ajax/backgroundworker.ashx",
    data: 'element=' + $(this).parent().siblings('.datarow').children('.dataelement').text(),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        var taData = data.split("|");
        if (taData[0] != "-1") {

            $(".dataelement:contains('" + taData[0] + "')").parent().siblings().children('.displayfield').text(taData[1]);
            $(".dataelement:contains('" + taData[0] + "')").parent().siblings().children('.img_throbber').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        else {
            alert("There is currently a problem accessing the background service that is responsible for data processing.");
            $('.do_work_button').css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".dataelement").parent().siblings().children('.dataelement').text("N/A");
            $(".dataelement").parent().siblings().children('.img_throbber').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        displayAjaxError(xhr);
        $(".dataelement").parent().siblings().children('.img_throbber').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
```

the $.ajax command is called with a click event on your page. and the .ashx (asp.net web handler file) is kinda like the vehichle you can use to get data from your client side to server side.  you can reference server side objects and code in the .ashx that use the data from the client side ajax call to return results via the http context.

Comment: Thanks for this! I just downloaded the toolkit from codeplex.